# After the spinner is spin and saving logic occurs, my tab icons vanish and the settings gear is unclickable. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationbar, tabbar

Following a fix for a nested NavigationView issue (i fixed it so that there's only one root navigationview in my ContentView), my tab icons vanish and the settings gear becomes unresponsive post-spinner use, and saving logic occurs. What might be the cause?

I tried to create a custom navigationbar for the settings gear but the problem persists. As of the tab icons I've been changing codes around but I haven't found a solution yet. These are my codes related to the issue. Let me know if you'd like to see more.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var refreshKey: UUID = UUID()

    
    enum Page {
        case onboarding_1, signupView, onboarding_2, onboarding_3, mainTabView, mainSettingsView, animatedPicker, exercisePage, group11ContainerView  // Removed the period at the end.
    }
    
    @Published var currentPage: Page = .onboarding_1 {
        didSet {
            print("Transitioned from \(oldValue) to \(currentPage)")
        }
    }


    
}
@main
struct MoveMintApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
           
           ContentView()  // Use ContentView instead of MainTabView since it manages the routing
                    .environmentObject(viewRouter)
            .environmentObject(SelectedTabIndex())
            .environmentObject(DateManager())
        }
    }
}
////////

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    @State private var refreshKey: UUID = UUID() 
    
    @State private var chosenDifficulty: Difficulty = .easy
       @State private var chosenExerciseName: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            switch viewRouter.currentPage {
            case .onboarding_1:
                Onboarding_1().id(viewRouter.refreshKey)
            case .signupView:
                SignUpView()
            case .onboarding_2:
                Onboarding_2()
            case .onboarding_3:
                Onboarding_3()
            case .mainTabView:
                MainTabView()
            case .mainSettingsView:
                MainSettingsView().environmentObject(viewRouter)
            case .animatedPicker:
                AnimatedPicker()
            case .group11ContainerView:
                Group11ContainerView(exerciseLog: ExerciseLog.shared).environmentObject(viewRouter)
            case .exercisePage:
                ExercisePage(difficulty: chosenDifficulty, exerciseName: $chosenExerciseName).environmentObject(viewRouter)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
/////////


import SwiftUI

class SelectedTabIndex: ObservableObject {
    @Published var index: Int = 0
}

class DateManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedDate: Date = Date()
}

struct MainTabView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var selectedTabIndex: SelectedTabIndex
    @EnvironmentObject var dateManager: DateManager
    @StateObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
    
    @State private var showSettings: Bool = false  // State for sheet presentation
    
    private let customGreen = Color(hex: "7BB38C")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                    CustomNavigationBar(title: "Main Tab", trailingAction: {
                        showSettings.toggle()
                    })
        
            TabView(selection: $selectedTabIndex.index) {
                AnimatedPicker()
                    .environmentObject(viewRouter)
                    .tabItem {
                        tabImage(named: "Running", forTab: 0)
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                
                Group11ContainerView(exerciseLog: ExerciseLog.shared)
                    .environmentObject(viewRouter)
                    .environmentObject(DateManager())
                    .environmentObject(ExerciseLog.shared)
                  
                    .tabItem {
                        tabImage(named: "Group 11", forTab: 1)
                    }
                    .tag(1)
            }
        
            .accentColor(customGreen)
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showSettings) {
                            MainSettingsView()
                                .environmentObject(viewRouter)
                                .environmentObject(SelectedTabIndex())
                                .environmentObject(DateManager())
                        }
                    
                
            /*.sheet(isPresented: $showSettings) {  // Present the MainSettingsView as a sheet
                MainSettingsView()
                    .environmentObject(viewRouter)  // Ensure viewRouter is passed
                    .environmentObject(SelectedTabIndex())
                    .environmentObject(DateManager()) */
    
            
        }
    }

    private func tabImage(named name: String, forTab tab: Int) -> some View {
        Image(name)
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .foregroundColor(selectedTabIndex.index == tab ? customGreen : .gray)
    }
}



extension Color {
    init(fromHex hex: String) {
        let hex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        var int: UInt64 = 0
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt64(&int)
        let r, g, b: UInt64
        switch hex.count {
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (r, g, b) = (int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            (r, g, b) = (123, 179, 140)
        }
        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double(r) / 255,
            green: Double(g) / 255,
            blue:  Double(b) / 255,
            opacity: 1
        )
    }
}
//////////
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct MainSettingsView: View {
    @State private var userName: String = ""  // This will be loaded from the database (like Firebase) after sign up.
    @State private var navigateToEditInfo: Bool = false
    @State private var profilePicture: Image?  // Placeholder, you should fetch this from a data source.
    @State private var navigateToChangePasswordView: Bool = false
    @State private var navigateToLogoutView: Bool = false
    
    @State private var isLogoutOverlayVisible: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter


    
    var body: some View {
       
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .frame(width: 439, height: 220)
                        .background(Color(red: 0.3, green: 0.73, blue: 0.61))
                        .cornerRadius(30)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    
                    VStack {
                        // Placeholder profile picture.
                        if let userImage = profilePicture {
                            userImage
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .padding(.top, 20)
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .padding(.top, 20)
                        }
                        
                        HStack {
                            TextField("", text: $userName)
                                .font(Font.custom("Spartan", size: 24).weight(.bold))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .disabled(true)
                                .padding(.leading, 130)
                            
                            Button(action: { self.navigateToEditInfo.toggle() }) {
                                Image("pencil")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 130)
                            }
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }
                
                Button(action: { self.navigateToChangePasswordView.toggle() }) {
                                 HStack {
                                     Text("Change Password")
                                         .font(Font.custom("Spartan", size: 16))
                                         .kerning(0.48)
                                         .foregroundColor(.black)
                                         .frame(width: 206, alignment: .leading)
                                     Spacer()
                                     Image("chevron")
                                         .frame(width: 10.2266, height: 24)
                                 }
                             }
                             .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // Makes sure the entire button area is clickable

                Button(action: { self.isLogoutOverlayVisible.toggle() }) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Logout")
                            .font(Font.custom("Spartan", size: 16))
                            .kerning(0.48)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(width: 206, alignment: .leading)
                        Spacer()
                        Image("chevron")
                            .frame(width: 10.2266, height: 24)
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .overlay(
                    Group {
                        if isLogoutOverlayVisible {
                            LogoutView(
                                onConfirm: {
                                    print("Perform logout here")
                                    self.isLogoutOverlayVisible.toggle()
                                    print("Logged out!")
                                },
                                onCancel: {
                                    self.isLogoutOverlayVisible.toggle()
                                
                                },
                                onLoggedOut: {
                                    // Additional logic after logout can be added here
                                },
                                isOverlayVisible: $isLogoutOverlayVisible
                            )
                            .environmentObject(viewRouter)  // Provide the viewRouter here
                        }
                    }
                )


                Button(action: {
                    print("Back to Exercise button tapped!")
                    viewRouter.currentPage = .mainTabView
                    print("Current page after button tapped: \(viewRouter.currentPage)")
                }) {
                    
                    /* Text("Back to Exercise")
                     .font(
                     Font.custom("Spartan", size: 24)
                     .weight(.heavy)
                     )
                     .kerning(0.72)
                     .foregroundColor(.white)
                     }
                     .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                     .padding(.vertical, 33)
                     .frame(width: 360, height: 79, alignment: .center)
                     .background(Color(red: 0.22, green: 0.77, blue: 0.38))
                     .cornerRadius(20)
                     .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.08), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 4)*/
                }

                             Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Terms of Use")
                      .font(Font.custom("Spartan", size: 12))
                      .kerning(0.36)
                      .underline()
                      .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Text("Private Policy")
                      .font(Font.custom("Spartan", size: 12))
                      .kerning(0.36)
                      .underline()
                      .foregroundColor(.black)
                }

                         }
                         .padding()
                         .sheet(isPresented: $navigateToEditInfo) {
                             EditInfoPage().environmentObject(viewRouter)
                         }
                         .sheet(isPresented: $navigateToChangePasswordView) {
                             ChangePasswordView().environmentObject(viewRouter)
                         
                         }
                         .onAppear {
                             fetchUserName()
                         }
                     
                       
      
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    
        }
    
    
    // Moved fetchUserName() function outside of the NavigationView body.
    func fetchUserName() {
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            // Here we're assuming the user's display name is what you want. Adjust as needed.
            self.userName = user.displayName ?? "Unknown Name"
        }
    }
}

struct MainSettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainSettingsView()
    }
}
///////////
import SwiftUI

struct CustomNavigationBar: View {
    let title: String
    let trailingAction: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()  // Push the title and the button to opposite ends
            Text(title)
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: trailingAction) {
                Image("gear")  // Assuming you have a gear image in your assets
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top, 20)  // Add space for status bar
        .background(Color.customGreen)
    }
}
```

Comment: A `TabView` cant exist inside a `NavigationView`